# How to edit a value that we have fetched from the Database using Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am a bit stuck here. I wanted to edit certain field that I get from the database using Stored Procedure. I am trying to send the email inforamtion for which I have stored all the stuff in a table "Email". Once I get the information from the table "Email", I want to edit the information of the body that I get from the database and then send it across to the user using the Email Service I have created. Below is what I have done till now. I have created a Hash table and have stored values there:

```
MembershipUser qiUser = ((GenericMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).GetUser(objSubAccount.CreatedByUser, false);

            Hashtable mailKeywords = new Hashtable();
            mailKeywords.Add("[AccountNumber]", objSubAccount.AccountNumber);
            mailKeywords.Add("[AccountSubmissionDate]", objSubAccount.SubmittedOn.ToString());
            mailKeywords.Add("[FBONameTitle]", objSubAccount.FBO1FirstName.Trim().Length == 0 && objSubAccount.FBO1MiddleInitial.Trim().Length == 0 && objSubAccount.FBO1LastName.Trim().Length == 0
            ? objSubAccount.FBO1AccountTitling : objSubAccount.FBO1FirstName + " " + objSubAccount.FBO1MiddleInitial + " " + objSubAccount.FBO1LastName);
            mailKeywords.Add("[QIName]", objSubAccount.CompanyName);
            mailKeywords.Add("[QIUserName]", qiUser.UserName);
            mailKeywords.Add("[QIUserEmailAddress]", qiUser.Email);
            mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification1]", objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification1);
            mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification2]", objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification2);
            mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification3]", objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification3);
```

Now I have assigned these values to different properties of the class EmailContent as:

```
EmailContent objEmailContent = new EmailContent();
            objEmailContent = EmailContent.GetEmailContentType(EmailContentType.WireroomGroup);
            objEmailContent.To = BancorpConfig.WireroomReceiverEmail;
            objEmailContent.Sender = BancorpConfig.WireRoomSenderEmail;
            objEmailContent.Subject = EmailContent.ReplacePlaceHolder(objEmailContent.Subject, mailKeywords);
            objEmailContent.Body = EmailContent.ReplacePlaceHolder(objEmailContent.Body, mailKeywords);
            objEmailContent.From = BancorpConfig.WireRoomSenderEmail;
            objEmailContent.MailDate = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Now what I want to do is when I get the value in objEmailContent.Body, I want to edit it in terms as if their is no value in the column WireEmailNotificaion1 then the bracket "()" should be removed. If their is a WireEmailNotification1, then the value should be displayed as (aa@gmail.com) else no value should be displayed removing the bracket too.

The body of the email is as below:

```
New QI Sub Account Application Submitted<br />
Account Number: ([AccountNumber])<br />
FBO Name/Account Title: ([FBONameTitle]) <br />
Application Submitted Date: ([AccountSubmissionDate])<br />
QI Name: ([QIName])<br />QI User Name: ([QIUserName])<br />
QI User Email Address: ([QIUserEmailAddress])<br />
Wire Email Notification 1: ([WireEmailNotification1])<br/>
Wire Email Notification 2: ([WireEmailNotification2])<br/>
Wire Email Notification 3: ([WireEmailNotification3])<br/>
Please add account to the Caller ID’s on Schedule A of the Wire Agreement.
```

How will I be able to remove the bracket from the body if their is no value in the WireEmailNotification1, WireEmailNotification2, WireEmailNotification3?

Comment: Please add how the body looks like.

Comment: After you replace all keywords call `body.Replace("()", "")`

Comment: I already tried this, but it was not giving me the correct result

Comment: I added this code after assigning values from to the objEmailContent.

Comment: Where is the code of ReplacePlaceHolder?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, you have a template and you want to take some values from database and put it in the message body.
When i had this requirement, i actually created and HTML template and the place where you want  to put the dynamic content, define some tags (like you have done) and then find each tag and replace it with respective field.

Other option (not very good), then since you have everything in the database,  you can write a procedure the give you the final message body (it is easy to map the field in the procedure). You can use Exec 'select * from ' for this.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a possibility for you?:

- Remove the brackets from the template.
- use a ternary operator to add them only when needed

example:

```
mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification1]", objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification1 != "" ? "(" + objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification1 + ")" : "" );
```

this is the same as saying (notice brackets):

```
        if (objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification1 != "")
        {
            mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification1]", "(" + objSubAccount.WireEmailNotification1+ ")" ); 
        }
        else
        {
            mailKeywords.Add("[WireEmailNotification1]","");
        }
```